# Is it possible to show math formula codes in Moodle?

Tags: latex, moodle, mathjax

In moodle foruns, the string "\(" enters math mode and "\)" leaves it. Is it possible to use some kind of verbatim mode to prevent code compilation of a particular formula?

The goal is to teach students how to write math formulas, with texts like this:

```
In order to show 'x squared', you must write \\( x^2 \\)".
```